# Run python file within python script, passing arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, arguments

I've been struggling with this problem for at least 1 hour, now I give up, I need your precious help..

What I'm trying to do, is to run a python script within a python script, passing some arguments.

until now, I've done this using a bat file, like this:

**test.bat**

```
...
SET fileName='c:\works\files\file.xml'
SET url='someurl'
SET table='tablename'
c:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" upload_data --config_file=C:\works\config.yaml --filename="%fileName%" --url="%url%" --kind="%table%"
```

this works great. Now I need to call that script within another python script, like this:

**test.py**

```
...
fileName = 'c:\works\files\file.xml'
url = 'someurl'
table = 'tablename'
if(os.path.exists(fileName):
  print 'exists!'
  #launch appcfg.py here!!
else:
  print 'file missing'
```

the file is correctly found, the `'exists!` message is correctly shown, but I don't know how to call that python file now.. I've tryed these two commands, but they don't work (maybe it's the white space in the path? I don't know how to get rit of that..)

**first attempt: fail**

```
os.system('c:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" upload_data --config_file=C:\works\config.yaml --filename='+fileName+' --url='+url+' --kind='+table)
```

**second attempt: double fail**

```
subprocess.call(['c:\Python27\python.exe','"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" upload_data --config_file=C:\works\config.yaml --filename='+fileName+' --url='+url+' --kind='+table ])
```

I hope I did not some copy/paste errors, the point is that I don't know how to pass so many arguments to another script, calling it inside the main python script..

I'm in your hands, thanks in advance, best regards

Comment: *UPDATE* I've fixed those copy paste errors that @Kindall pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your first attempt's failure is obvious:

```
os.system('c:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" upload_data --config_file=C:\works\config.yaml --filename='+fileName+' --url='+url+' --kind='+table+')
```

This is a syntax error; you have an extra `+` sign and apostrophe before the closing parenthesis.  In other words, that line should end:

```
... +table)
```

The reoson for your second attempt's failure is equally obvious:

```
subprocess.call(['c:\Python27\python.exe','"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" upload_data --config_file=C:\works\config.yaml --filename='+fileName+' --url='+url+' --kind='+table+' ])
```

It's the same problem as your first, *plus* you have failed to break up the individual arguments to the command into separate list items as is required by `subprocess.call()`. You also don't need the double quotes around arguments that contain spaces (these are hints to the shell as to what's an argument; this is not needed here since the shell won't be handling this and you've already broken up the arguments). In other words, it should look more like:

```
subprocess.call(['c:\Python27\python.exe','C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py', 'upload_data', '--config_file=C:\works\config.yaml',  '--filename='+fileName, '--url='+url, '--kind='+table])
```

Now you still have a problem... the backslashes. Backslash is an escape character in Python string literals, causing the next character to have a special meaning. Most of the backslashes in your strings do not precede a character with any special meaning so they won't cause any problems... however, there is `\a` which is converted to ASCII BEL (which beeps the terminal).

There are three approaches for dealing with backslashes, which you need to employ any time you use backslashes in a string literal:

- Double all your backslashes. Python interprets two backslashes as a single backslash and the following character is not given any special meaning.
- Use raw string literals by preceding the string literal with `r`. This causes the backslash to lose its special meaning (well, sorta, it doesn't work quite as you expect if the backslash is the last thing in the string).
- For Windows pathnames, just use forward slashes instead of backslashes. Windows is happy with either!

Using the third option here, we have:

```
subprocess.call(['c:/Python27/python.exe','C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py', 'upload_data', '--config_file=C:/works/config.yaml',  '--filename='+fileName, '--url='+url, '--kind='+table])
```

Starting another Python process is a kind of heavyweight way to do something like this; there may be a better way, such as `import`ing the script and calling its `main()` method.

Comment: whops, that + was a copy paste error.. I'll try your last solution right now!

Comment: first of all, thanks. I get this error: *c:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '"C:\Program Files <x86>\Google\google_appengineppcfy.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument*.. It's like the \a in the path is magically eated or interpreted..

Comment: Oh yeah, `\a` is an escape for ASCII 7 (bell). I looked to see whether the backslashes would cause any problem, but missed that one. I've added a section on dealing with the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you import the other python script? You can then pass the correct arguments to it's main function.

Edit: Here's [appcfg.py's source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/appcfg.py). This should help you find what function you need.

Edit 2:
Here's some code to help:

```
import appcfg
appcfg_globals = dict([(var, eval('appcfg.' + var))for var in dir(appcfg)])
# Insert arguments into appcfg_globals
appcfg.run_file_(appcfg.__file__, appcfg_globals)
```

How it works:
dir(module)
lists all the variables in 'module' like so:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', [...]]
```

But we want a dict of the form:

```
{
 '__builtins__': {[...]},
 '__doc__': [...],
 '__file__': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py',
 '__name__': 'appcfg',
 '__package__': [...],
 [...]
}
```

So we get the values associated to the names using eval, and associate them to there name in a tuple like this: (variable_name, variable_value).
dict() does the rest!

All that's left to do is insert you arguments. I'll let you find that on you own!

Proof this works:

my_test.py:

```
my_globals = globals()
```

In Python:

```
>>> import my_test
>>> my_test.my_globals == dict([(var, eval('my_test.' + var))for var in dir(my_test)])
True
```

Comment: Can you explain me how? I'm a python newbye.. Do you need the appcfg.py code? It's from appengine sdk, by google. can I provide it?

Comment: I added a link to the source so you can see how to execute appcfg.py

Comment: uhm.. I don't really know how to call that inside my script.. __file__ is the argument array?

Comment: __file__ is the current file. So here it's the path to appcfg.py

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing somehting like this.

```
os.system("appcfg.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

I would look into this portion of the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) documentation.

Goodluck.

Comment: and all the other arguments?